# View shifting upwards due to transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios

I am using  a certain piece of code to make my navigation bar transparent. But what is doing it it is shifting the view which is below the navigation bar like my toolbar and then it is coinciding with my title of the navigation bar.

The code is as follows:-

```
(void)SetNavigationBarTransparent:(UINavigationController *)navicon{
NSLog(@"the navigation bar in app delegate is %@", navicon);
// these lines are for making the navigation bar transparent and making it submersible 
  with the view below it.
navicon.navigationBar.translucent = YES; // Setting this slides the view up, underneath 
the nav bar (otherwise it'll appear black)
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: 
CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];


[navicon.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
//remove shadow
if ([navicon.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)])
{
    [navicon.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
}

}
```

So what can I do to prevent my view from shifting upwards as I want my bar to be transparent for sure with all the bar buttons and title intact and  visible.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

The view's autoresizing is as follows:[image]

what can I do here to make it stay at its place.

Answer (score 0):

Set view's `autoresize mask` to fixed top margin using storyboard or code.

Comment: You need to switch the upper margin to no line (fixed) instead of red line (adjustable).

Comment: I have switched the red line by clicking on it but still it is not changing and the view is still shifting upwards coinciding with the navigation bar. So, what can I do now.

Comment: Try  removing setShadowImage code, then try with both Translucent=Yes and NO. What do you see?

Comment: no its not working when I remove the setShadow image code there is  black line coming at the bottom and the view is still shifting upwards. Please help.